# How to check jQuery plugin and functions exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, marquee

I have a plugin in some pages but in some other pages I don't want it so I didn't reference its script file.

How to check if the plugin functions exist before using it.

In my case I am using this plugin:  and I use it like this:

```
$('#marquee-inner div').marquee('pointer').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).trigger('stop');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).trigger('start');
}).mousemove(function(event) {
    if ($(this).data('drag') == true) {
        this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollX') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX);
    }
}).mousedown(function(event) {
    $(this).data('drag', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollX', this.scrollLeft);
}).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).data('drag', false);
});
```

What I want is to make a check before calling this marquee function if it exist or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a jQuery plugin is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
if ($.fn.marquee) {
    // there is some jquery plugin named 'marquee' on your page
}
```

Comment: Pure JS solution for this? Without $ sign??

Comment: Is there any chance to create this function name dynamically? I mean like $.fn.variableFunctionName? I tried to find information how to concatenate it but with no success.

Comment: @ErykWróbel I think you're looking for [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation): `$.fn['someString']` or `$.fn[someVariable]`.

Answer (score 20):

You can also do this. Let me take jQuery marquee example.

This is good if you are using only jQuery.

```
if($().marquee) {
    // marquee is loaded and available
}
```

OR

```
if($.fn.marquee !== undefined) {
    // marquee is loaded and available
}
```

Similar to above but Safe when you are using other JS frameworks Mootools etc.

```
if(jQuery().marquee) {
    // marquee is loaded and available
}
```

OR

```
if(jQuery.fn.marquee !== undefined) {
    // marquee is loaded and available
}
```

Comment: It would be better use of !== "undefined" since !== and === compare direct to the string type of the object. so basically what you are compare is the string type, I know is work but maybe would be more "correct" to use the quotes...

Answer (score 4):

Slightly better:

```
if ($.isFunction($.fn.marquee)) {
    // ...
}
```

Maybe a little overkill, but this will ensure that it's at least a function.

**Update January 2021:**

Since `jQuery.isFunction()` has been deprecated as of version 3.3, the easiest & recommended way to check this is now:

```
if (typeof $.fn.marquee === "function") {
    // ...
}
```

Note that this may not be enough for certain very old browsers—see the [`$.isFunction()` implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.x-stable/src/var/isFunction.js) for details.