# How to check if function exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if is function on jquery, but function is in another .js file?

validation.js:

```
if ($.isFunction('payment')) {
    $('[data-numeric]').payment('restrictNumeric');
    $('.cc-number').payment('formatCardNumber');
    $('.cc-exp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
    $('.cc-cvc').payment('formatCardCVC');
}
```

this is false because func payments is in the payments.js .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript check if function exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042138/javascript-check-if-function-exists)

Comment: You want to check if jQuery `$` has the function defined. Ex. `$.myFunc`

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type

Comment: If it's specifically jQuery functions (though the fact that they are registered in jquery is pretty much irrelevant, a function is just a function regardless of where it is registered) there is also this [How to check jQuery plugin and functions exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339876/how-to-check-jquery-plugin-and-functions-exists)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

problem is solved. its works:

```
if ($.fn.payment) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 40):

Try like this

```
if (typeof payment === "function")
{
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: `if is function on jquery, but function is in another .js file`

Answer (score 9):

Try to check like as follows,

```
 if (typeof payment !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(payment)) {
    $('[data-numeric]').payment('restrictNumeric');
    $('.cc-number').payment('formatCardNumber');
    $('.cc-exp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
    $('.cc-cvc').payment('formatCardCVC');
 }
```

Comment: `if is function on jquery, but function is in another .js file`

Comment: files are irrelevant in js @Tushar. The "exists" is whether it is in the current scope of the window. The "files" simply add objects(functions) to the scope. What are you getting at?

Comment: @Liam He want to check if jQuery `$` has the function defined. Ex. $.myFunc

Answer (score 6):

You can check if a function exists using `window`

For example

```
var fn = window['NameOfTheFunction']; 
if(typeof fn === 'function') {
    doSomething();
}
```

If your function in payment.js is part of a self contained function, you need to set it to so the window object can "see" it by adding this in your self contained function:

```
window.NameOfTheFunction = NameOfTheFunction;
```