# how to check if a function exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to check if a function exists?

accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215901/) but it doesn't work

```js
function sb_save(){
alert('saving');
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
 if ($.fn.sb_save){sb_save();}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: How could it not be there? You declared it already, right?  
If it's a case that it might not be there, you can just easily check if is truthy by if(sb_save) or just by checking if it's type equals "function"

Comment: `typeof sb_save === "function"` doesn't work for you?

Comment: `$.fn` is  jquery object property. The function shown has nothing to do with jQuery. What would make you think that conditional would ever be truthy?

Comment: Why are checking if `$.fn.sb_save` exists and later calling `sb_save`?

Comment: I'm VTC as dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sb_save(){
alert('saving');
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
 if (typeof sb_save==="function"){
sb_save();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: This is mentioned in the question linked by OP *"but it doesn't work"*

Comment: this condition seems to be truthy anytime.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sb_save(){
    alert('saving');
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
    if (typeof sb_save === 'function') {
        sb_save();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: *As of jQuery 3.3, jQuery.isFunction() has been deprecated. In most cases, its use can be replaced by typeof x === "function"*

Comment: You don't really need the `undefined` check

Answer (score -1):

Given the code example you show, you are trying to check if jQuery has been extended using that function:

```
if ($.fn.sb_save)
```

The way you're trying to call the function

```
sb_save();
```

shows this is not what you intended.

Instead, to simply check if `sb_save` is an executable object (a.k.a. `function`), use the most upvoted answer from the question you linked:

```
if (typeof sb_save === 'function')
```

```js
function sb_save() {
  alert('saving');
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  if (typeof sb_save === 'function') {
    sb_save();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```