# Finding if a jquery plugin/function is available. Diff between $.pluginName() and $().pluginName()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect if a jQuery plugin is available, I tried

```
$.pluginName
```

but failed then tried

```
$().pluginName
```

it works. But whats the difference between the 2?

Comment: Did you try just `$.pluginName`, without the brackets? That's what I'd try first.

Comment: Read here : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: @sje397, actually I did without the braces, I still got undefined

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if a jquery plugin is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-to-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking at `$.fn.pluginName`. jQuery's `$.fn` is an alias for `$.prototype` and that's where all the plugin names go.  The top-level `$.*` namespace is reserved for jQuery's utility functions such as [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

Answer (score 3):

You can look at this stackoverflow question only, they discussed a lot about this

[How can I check if a jQuery plugin is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-to-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded)