# jQuery Cycle issue in FF 7.0.1 on Windows and OS X

Tags: jquery, cycle

The cycle plugin does not appear to be loading in FF on both OS X and Windows. Nothing is happening when I inspect the dom via Firebug. I am using this test:

```
 if (window.cycle) {
        console.log("cycle loaded")
     }
```

This test fails in FF, but passes in Chrome, and IE 7+ (and Cycle works as well)

Thoughts?

Comment: I wonder what your `<script>` tags look like.

Comment: my cycles are working for me on FF 7.0.1, but I don't use that test.  You say Cycle works as well, does that mean that it works but the test for window.cycle returns false?

Comment: OK — I don't think that test does what I thought, because it breaks it in FF. I was calling cycle like this: $(window).load(function() {
    if(window.cycle){
            $("#cycle").cycle({
            fx: "fade",
            speed: 800,
            timeout: 4000 
            });
     }
}); Trying to only attach the plugin if the plugin was being called on that page. I removed the cycle test, and it works in FF.

Comment: This is what I needed to do:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-to-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this...
`if (jQuery().cycle) {`