# error prone jquery extending

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anybody familiar with patterns for:

- Checking for existing jQuery extension most safely?
- And how to exit    from it safely if code can not be executed.

Like

```
(function($){
    if (jQuery.fn.pluginName)
    ......
    }
})(jQuery);
```

10x, BR

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded - basically - if(jQuery().pluginName) {
     //run plugin dependent code
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $.fn namespace is populated with functions. If the plugin exists you can use this

```
if ($.fn.myPlugin instanceof Function) {
    // the plugin exists
} else {
    // the plugin does not exist
}
```

Also if that wasnt enough, you can also check using

```
if (typeof $.fn.myPlugin === 'function') {
    // The plugin exists
} else {
    // The plugin does not exist
}
```