# Detect included jQuery UI Plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, plugins, console

Is there any way to detect what jQuery-UI plugins are available in a website? In particular, I am curious as to whether there is an easy console.log() or console echo command (like $.ui.version) that would list available plugins.

Part 2 of the question would be how to add plugins to an existing jUI setup without overwriting the entire library, but we'll save that one for later :)

Comment: [How can I check if a jQuery plugin is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/400916)

Comment: Useful, but requires knowledge of a specific plugin name. Could make this work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to parse through `$.ui` object . It contains all the jQueryUI widget methods but also contains other methods. Inspect it in a browser console to see what it contains. You could build an array of widget names and then check the names in array exist in `$.ui`