# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'featureList'

Tags: javascript

Its a slider, but the slide effect doesn't work anymore.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.featureList(
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method         'featureList'
    $("#tabs li a"),
    $("#output li"), {
        start_item  :   0
    }
);
});
</script>
```

What is in my indexfile is the following.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.featureList(
    $("#tabs li a"),
    $("#output li"), {
        start_item  :   0
    }
);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please realise that Javascript is not the same as Java.

Comment: Have you definitely loaded the `$.featureList` plugin? Has it definitely loaded?

Comment: How can I load it? sorry i'm not familiar with this

Answer (score 1):

The method `featureList` is only defined if the plugin is loaded. There is one of two problems:

`$` is not `jQuery` (you are using an other library that binds the `$` to their library). You can combat this by using a self-invoking function:

```
(function( $ ) {
  //Your code...
})( jQuery );
```

More likely though, is that your plugin is not loaded (e.g. you misspelled the path to the plugin script is located). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded) how to detect if a jQuery plugin is loaded.