# Check if grid is initialized

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am using slick grid. I have an input textbox. Whenever the content changes, I need to refesh the grid. So I set explicitInitialization as true.

I call

```
grid.init();
grid.invalidate();
```

in input textbox onchange. This works fine.

But I don't wan't to call init() every time. So, how to check if the grid is initialized?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a jQuery plugin is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded)

Comment: @PatsyIssa I think OP wants to call the `init` function only when a particular element is visible on the screen, so it's completely unrelated.

Comment: @pawel read the question again ` So, how to check if the grid is visible of if it is initialized? `

Comment: @PatsyIssa "It works fine". So the plugin is loaded and has been successfully executed. Now OP wants to optimize. However without more code/fiddle it qualifies to be closed, just not as a duplicate of what you've linked to.

Comment: @PatsyIssa Sorry that was a mistake. I updated it now.