# Adding Library on the web app with broccoli

Tags: ember.js, broccolijs

I am using a jquery library, here http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/iPod-Style-jQuery-Sliding-Drill-Down-Menu-Plugin.html, and I'm trying to add it on my app. These are my import statements:

```
app.import('other_components/drilldown/css/linkes_drilldown.css');
app.import('other_components/drilldown/src/linkes_drilldown.js');
```

To be use to use that library, the function `linkesDrillDown()` has to be called as `$('.drillDownMenu').linkesDrillDown();`. When calling this function, the following error is being produced:

```
undefined is not a function
```

which basically means that the library is not being loaded. Any idea, is there anything wrong with the import statements?

Comment: What is the specific error that you are getting?

Comment: the import statement seems correct whenever your path is the correct one. Are you sure of your jQuery selector what's the output of `console.log($('.drillDownMenu').length);` can you also check properly that your plugin is loaded for example by using this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded

Comment: the selector is okk, the plugin is not loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this plugin is not available via Bower. Put the plugin contents in the `vendor` folder and modify the import statements to be like

```
app.import('vendor/drilldown/css/linkes_drilldown.css');
app.import('vendor/drilldown/src/linkes_drilldown.js');
```