# How to know in script is Bootstrap 3 added

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the best and cross-browser way to know in javascript that Bootstrap 3 has already added on the page?

Answer (score 1):

One potential way is to simply check for the presence of the various Bootstrap plugins you're utilizing. For example:

```
if(typeof $.fn.modal === 'function') {
  //it's on the page
}
```

All jQuery plugins are added to the jQuery prototype and their existence can be checked on the `jQuery.fn` property. See [How can I check if a jQuery plugin is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded)

More simply, you could just do:

```
if($.fn.modal) {
  //it's on the page
}
```

Looking at Bootstrap's JS source, it doesn't seem to drop any globals that you could check for.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best answer - bootstrap.js adds a lot of extensions to the jQuery - things like $.fn.button. If you are using standard bootstrap package you can check as follows:

```
if (typeof $.fn.button === 'function' && typeof $.fn.button.Constructor === 'function') {
    // $.fn.button.Constructor.VERSION contains current version 
}
```

If you don't use bootstrap.js at all or you use custom version of the bootstrap library then this way may not work.