# Checking to see if a plugin has been initialized in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using the [select2](https://select2.github.io/) jQuery plugin (**V4**) and from what I can see they don't have an `onInitialized` event; but I need to run some code *after* it has been initialized.

By **Initialized** I mean that it has completed and that all elements associated to it are now ready.

I seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400916/how-can-i-check-if-a-jquery-plugin-is-loaded), but none of the answers seem to address the issue of continually checking until it becomes available; like what if it's not there the first time you check, then the code you needed to run wouldn't run.

I thought of using `setInterval` with something like the above but wasn't sure if there was a better way?

Comment: Just checking what you mean by "initialised": Do you want to check that Select2 is download and registered as a jQuery function before calling it with `$('select').select2();`? Or do you want to check that `$('select').select2();` is complete before doing something else?

Comment: @Lesley Sorry, I mean *completed*. I have updated my question.

Comment: The question you linked to is about checking that a plugin is downloaded and registered as a jQuery function. If you want to do something after the call to `select2()` is complete, my first thought was:

Why not just put the code for the stuff you want to do post-init after the call to Select2?

    `$('#my-select').select2();
    console.log('This should happen after select2() is done');`

Comment: @Lesley Whilst you are giving it the command *after* the call to `select2` since JavaScript is synchronous and not asynchronous by default then wouldn't this mean that `select2` may not necessarily be finished executing when you run code after it?

Comment: It depends what Select2 is doing under the hood... I suppose it's possible it says `return` before it's really finished and then does further work due to some async callback or whatever. Do you have a situation which is indicating this is the case?

Comment: @Lesley Not really, just wanted to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can go async it's when you fetching remote data, so you can inject you callback in that ajax.

If you have several ajax calls use deferred:

```
var deffered1 = $.Deferred();
```

In your ajax calls after `success` and `error` use the following code to resolve those calls.

```
complete:function(){
    deffered1.resolve()
}
```

And to subscribe for events:

```
$.when(deffered1, deffered2).done(function() {
    // your initialized actions
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 `select` elements on your page which needs to be converted to `select2 dropdown` then you can use the following: [Multi Select version](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/tq6sL23t/2/)

if you have just a single select on the page, you can go with the following:
[Single Select option:](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/tq6sL23t/1/)

Hope it helps.